# How to save Int16Array buffer to wav file node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, buffer, wav, fs

I am sending Int16Array buffer to server while audio processing

```
var handleSuccess = function (stream) {
        globalStream = stream;
        input = context.createMediaStreamSource(stream);
        input.connect(processor);

        processor.onaudioprocess = function (e) {
            var left = e.inputBuffer.getChannelData(0);
    var left16 = convertFloat32ToInt16(left);
    socket.emit('binaryData', left16);
        };
    };

    navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(constraints)
        .then(handleSuccess);
```

and in server i am trying to save the file as follows

```
client.on('start-audio', function (data) {
        stream = fs.createWriteStream('tesfile.wav');
    });

    client.on('end-audio', function (data) {
         if (stream) {
            stream.end();
         }
         stream = null;
    });

    client.on('binaryData', function (data) {
        if (stream !== null) {
            stream.write(data);
        }
    });
```

But this is not working so how i save this array buffer as wav file?

Comment: I need to do the same... Did you have a solution now?

Comment: I've tried to use this https://github.com/Jam3/audiobuffer-to-wav but without any luck.

Comment: @Ravimallya is there a reproductive example in a repository maybe? Does this uses `socket.io`?

Comment: Yes @ChristosLytras, Here's a git https://github.com/ravimallya/angular-node-google-voice-api . nodejs server code (socket.io) inside /bin directory and audio recorder is inside src/app/dashboard component. I'm sending left16 array buffer. Live transcription works fine. However, I need to save recorded audio as wav file in server.

Comment: @Ravimallya please check my answer and the repository with a simple project that demonstrates the usage of the `wav` NPM package on server side.

Answer (score 6):

At the O/P question, there is an attempt to write and add data directly to an existing file which it can't work because WAVE files need to have a header and there can't be a header by just creating a write file stream using `createWriteStream`. You can check about that header format here ["WAVE PCM soundfile format"](http://soundfile.sapp.org/doc/WaveFormat/).

There is the [`wav`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/wav) NPM package which it can help to handle the whole process of writing the data to the server. It has the [`FileWriter`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/wav#filewriterpath-options) class which creates a stream that will properly handle WAVE audio data and it will write the header when the stream ends.

#### 1. Create a WAVE `FileWriter` stream on `start-audio` event:

```js
// Import wav package FileWriter
const WavFileWriter = require('wav').FileWriter;

...

// Global FileWriter stream.
// It won't handle multiple client connections; it's just for demonstration
let outputFileStream;

// The UUID of the filename that's being recorded
let id;

client.on('start-audio', function() {
  id = uuidv4();

  console.log(`start-audio:${id}`);

  // Create a FileWriter stream using UUID generated for filename
  outputFileStream = new WavFileWriter(`./audio/recs/${id}.wav`, {
    sampleRate: 16000,
    bitDepth: 16,
    channels: 1
  });
});
```

#### 2. Use the stream we created to write audio data on `binaryData` event:

```js
client.on('binaryData', function(data) {
  console.log(`binaryData:${id}, got ${data ? data.length : 0} bytes}`);

  // Write the data directly to the WAVE file stream
  if (outputFileStream) {
    outputFileStream.write(data);
  }
});
```

#### 3. End the stream when we receive `end-audio` event:

```js
client.on('end-audio', function() {
  console.log(`end-audio:${id}`);

  // If there is a stream, end it.
  // This will properly handle writing WAVE file header
  if (outputFileStream) {
    outputFileStream.end();
  }

  outputFileStream = null;
});
```

I have created a Github repository with this example which you can find here: https://github.com/clytras/node-wav-stream.

Keep in mind that handling data like this will result in issues because using this code, there is only one `FileWriter` stream variable for every client that connects. You should create an array for each client stream and use client session ID's to store and identify each stream item that belongs to the corresponding client.

Comment: Thanks a lot. One small change is needed to end the filestream. Instead of `if (outputFileStream) {` we have to check  `if (!outputFileStream.closed) {`.

Comment: I think you don't have to do that because if we have a stream `outputFileStream !== null` then it is not closed because we set `outputFileStream = null` on `end-audio` event. It's safer to check if it exists before you check if it's closed because if there isn't an object, then that check with `closed` will result in error. So better do `if (outputFileStream && !outputFileStream.closed) {`.

Comment: Yes, I second that.

Comment: I tried your solutions but it not converting proper wav file there is no audio inside it

Comment: @Vimal https://github.com/ravimallya/angular-node-google-voice-api you can give a try here. I've not updated the code, but this answer will surely help you. Let us know if you face any trouble.