# Concat stream audio buffers into one file and store it

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-cloud-platform, audio, wav

I was using the Google Cloud Speech to recognize streaming audios (from microphone) on the node server. At the same time I would like to store the streamed audio into a file. Since the streaming recognition is operated on chunks of buffers, how could I combine all the buffers and store it as a single audio file?

The actual code I was using is adapted from [this library](https://github.com/vin-ni/Google-Cloud-Speech-Node-Socket-Playground), where the audio encoding on the server side is defined as

```js
const encoding = 'LINEAR16';
const sampleRateHertz = 16000;
```

And each time there's a audio stream it will be sent via the cloud api:

```js
client.on('binaryData', function (data) {
    if (recognizeStream !== null) {
      recognizeStream.write(data);
    }
  });
```

On the client side, the buffer was preprocessed in [this file](https://github.com/vin-ni/Google-Cloud-Speech-Node-Socket-Playground/blob/master/src/public/js/recorderWorkletProcessor.js) (downsampled into a `Int16Array`).

So can I just concatenate each buffer and save to a `pcm` file on the server side, when the streaming finishes? Or do I need to merge the buffers in a complex way (such as using [audiobuffer-to-wav](https://github.com/Jam3/audiobuffer-to-wav)?

Comment: Maybe you could use some [`audio-combiner`](https://github.com/ttippin84/audio-combiner) to merge the audio on the server side.

Answer (score 0):

There is a SO answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51399121/how-to-save-int16array-buffer-to-wav-file-node-js) which solves exactly my question. It uses the `wav` library to add a header, and then write the audio buffer to a file.